# how to use MUI with Remix.run?

Tags: material-ui, node-modules, remix.run

the simple installation of MUI on remix works, but when it comes to complicated code, MUI codes show errors

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')

The stack trace is:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
at decomposeColor (file:///C:/Users/R.Darabi/WebstormProjects/cst.core.remixpanel/build/index.js?t=1702373889291.464:2092:14)
at getLuminance (file:///C:/Users/R.Darabi/WebstormProjects/cst.core.remixpanel/build/index.js?t=1702373889291.464:2133:12)
at getContrastRatio (file:///C:/Users/R.Darabi/WebstormProjects/cst.core.remixpanel/build/index.js?t=1702373889291.464:2138:14)
at Object.getContrastText (file:///C:/Users/R.Darabi/WebstormProjects/cst.core.remixpanel/build/index.js?t=1702373889291.464:2459:24)
at file:///C:/Users/R.Darabi/WebstormProjects/cst.core.remixpanel/build/index.js?t=1702373889291.464:167142:27
at muiStyledFunctionResolver (file:///C:/Users/R.Darabi/WebstormProjects/cst.core.remixpanel/build/index.js?t=1702373889291.464:2023:28)
at transformedStyleArg (file:///C:/Users/R.Darabi/WebstormProjects/cst.core.remixpanel/build/index.js?t=1702373889291.464:1943:83)
at handleInterpolation (C:\Users\R.Darabi\WebstormProjects\cst.core.remixpanel\node_modules@emotion\serialize\dist\emotion-serialize.cjs.dev.js:149:24)
at Object.serializeStyles (C:\Users\R.Darabi\WebstormProjects\cst.core.remixpanel\node_modules@emotion\serialize\dist\emotion-serialize.cjs.dev.js:263:15)
at C:\Users\R.Darabi\WebstormProjects\cst.core.remixpanel\node_modules@emotion\styled\base\dist\emotion-styled-base.cjs.dev.js:167:34

The error name is:
TypeError

Used Package Manager
npm

Expected Behavior
a simple mui admin dashboard with multiple languages

Actual Behavior
errors in using packages and peers